# Como duplicar ou clonar uma DIV em Java Script e ler todos os elementos em ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, aspx

Olá,

Tenho um formulário de convidados que preciso aumentar automaticamente os campos de acordo com o preenchimento.

O código é:

```
<div class="form-row" id="Guests">
<p><strong>Guests Forms</strong></p>
<div id="guest1">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="labelGuestNumber" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">1.</label>
        <label for="labelGuesName1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="margin-left: 5px;">
            <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputGuestName1" placeholder="Guest Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="margin-left: -40px;">
        <label for="labelCPFCNPJGuest1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" >CPF/CNPJ:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input runat="server" class="form-control" id="inputCPFCNPJGuest1" placeholder="CPF / CNPJ" onChange="newGuest()" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou seja, toda vez que preencher o CPF/CNPJ ele pode abrir mais uma linha para preencher outro convidado. Quando enviar esse formulário, preciso que seja lido em ASP.NET C# para ser inserido no banco de dados.

Não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Bom uma solução para o problema.

```
    function newGuest() {
  let clone = $("#guest1").clone();
  let count = $("#Guests [id^=guest]").length;
  clone.attr("id", "guest" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("label[for='labelGuestNumber']").html((count + 1) + ":");
  clone.find("label[for='labelGuesName1']").attr("for", "labelGuesName" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("#inputGuestName1").val("");
  clone.find("#inputGuestName1").attr("id", "inputGuestName" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("label[for='labelCPFCNPJGuest1']").attr("for", "labelCPFCNPJGuest" + (count + 1));
  clone.find("#inputCPFCNPJGuest1").val("");
  clone.find("#inputCPFCNPJGuest1").attr("id", "inputCPFCNPJGuest" + (count + 1));
  $("#Guests").append(clone);
}
```